# Angular 5: Warning a promise was rejected

Tags: angular, promise, angular5

I have just installed Angular 5 with angular-cli:

In the new app the following warning is spitted in console.

Don't know the reason why?

```
h1.js:25 Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]
     at g (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:11246)
     at i.n._warn (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:15804)
     at i._rejectCallback (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:45600)
     at Function.i.reject.i.rejected (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:41344)
     at chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:39:63684
     at i (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:72787)
     at i._settlePromiseFromHandler (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:46193)
     at i._settlePromise (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:46993)
     at i._settlePromise0 (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:47692)
     at i._settlePromises (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:49019)
     at o._drainQueue (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:2790)
     at o._drainQueues (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:2851)
     at drainQueues (chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/h1.js:25:984)
     at <anonymous>
```

Comment: This seems to be thrown by a chrome extension. Not by your app.

Comment: Here is the offending extension in this case: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/honey/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, you are correct. This warning is coming due to honey chrome extension. This will go away as soon as we uninstall it. Please State this as an answer. Thanks, Sridhar G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Benjamin Gruenbaum suggested Warning is coming from **Honey extension** if you had installed it. 
Link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/honey/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj